# Exporting each row of a 2D numpy array as a single element in csv column

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array which has a shape of (15015,262). I need to export it to a csv file so that **each row** of the numpy 2Darray is a **single element list** of the csv file (i.e., the csv file should have a shape of (15015,1).

I tried using the csv modules of python and the numpy modules but nothing seems to work properly. For example, I tried using

`with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for val in modified_seq_data:
        writer.writerow([val])`

In the above case (even though the csv file does get saved in a single column), when I call it back via np.genfromtxt (for a different code) I get the following output:

```
[nan nan nan nan nan ..... nan nan nan]
```

Somehow it is not able to export the csv into a numpy 1D array where each element is a list.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `modified_seq_data` is the numpy array:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(modified_seq_data.shape[0]):
        writer.writerow([modified_seq_data[i, :]])
```

Comment: This gives me the same problem - when I am calling the csv file again (in another program) it gives me [nan nan nan... nan nan nan] @Skyy2010

Comment: @Rohini Banerjee, Well I thought that is what you wanted. Each 1d numpy array as a list. What do you want then? Maybe you can write an example row of the csv file with  the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Does your single output list object have commas in it? If so, your reader could just be reading into those commas through the list. As far as the structure goes, which I think is the underlying issue here, you need 1 atomic value in each row to get the effect of the csv. So I would consider casting your list object into a big string separated by spaces, writing that out, then reading it in, splitting it, and casting the type back to what it is needed to be.

Hope this helps.
BC